# Prove by induction that $\forall$ $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there $\exists$ $m_n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m_n^2 \le n \lt (m_n + 1) ^ 2$.

Tags: analysis, induction

I have to prove that $\forall$ $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists some number $m_n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that the following equality holds:

$$m_n^2 \le n \lt (m_n + 1) ^ 2$$

(By the way, we use $\mathbb{N}$ here as the set $\{1, 2, 3...\}$, so without $0$)

So I basically have to prove that every natural number $1, 2, 3....$ can be bounded by two perfect squares. If I try some examples, this looks obvious:

$$1= 1^2 \le 1 \lt 2^2 = 4$$

$$1= 1^2 \le 2 \lt 2^2 = 4$$

$$1= 1^2 \le 3 \lt 2^2 = 4$$

$$4= 2^2 \le 4 \lt 3^2 = 9$$

$$4= 2^2 \le 5 \lt 3^2 = 9$$

$$...$$

But I don't know how to prove this with induction. Showing that $P(1)$ holds is obviously trivial. Then, say we assume $P(k)$ to be true, so we have:

$$P(k): m_k^2 \le k \lt (m_k + 1) ^ 2 \hspace{0.5cm} \text{true}$$

But I don't see how to apply the induction step and get to:

$$P(k+1) : m_{k+1}^2 \le k + 1 \lt (m_{k+1} + 1)^2$$

Comment: Is it specified that you have to use an induction ? It does not seem to be the most natural here. Just set $m_n = \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor$.

Comment: Often in problems like this, induction is a good first try.  Re TheSilverDoe's comment, this problem is an exception.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe That's a really nice solution! Thanks a lot for the idea. Unfortunately, it is stated that I have to use induction.

Answer (score 1):

Among integers, $a<b$ implies $a+1\le b$. Therefore, if
$$ m_k^2\le k<(m_k+1)^2$$
then
$$ m_k^2\le k+1\le (m_k+1)^2.$$

- If $k+1< (m_k+1)^2$, then $P(k+1)$ holds with $m_{k+1}:=m_k$.
- If $k+1=(m_k+1)^2$, then $P(k+1)$ holds with $m_{k+1}:=m_k+1$.

Comment: Can you please tell me why did you split the problem into those two cases (the two black dots at the end)? Did you split the second inequality from the second line?